# Finding UK population GIS data by city for free?

Tags: data, census, united-kingdom, population

I am looking for some gis data for free of the UK population by city.

I have found some in excel files but I am looking for other data formats(shapefile? CSV? I am not sure), data divided in smaller administrative districts.

Comment: This is a question that I think would be better researched/asked at the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 2):

A Google search for ["uk census spatial data"](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=uk+census+spatial+data) returns several results which contain datasets of census boundaries. This data could be combined with the data available on the [UK Census website](https://www.ons.gov.uk/census/) to create your spatial dataset of population.